# Merging javascript callbacks, soundmanager2 and waveform.js

Tags: javascript, this, soundmanager2

I'm attempting to build an audio player using soundmanager2, a soundcloud stream, and waveform.js (http://waveformjs.org/). The player itself is working, but trying to get the callback for waveform.js to run along side my own callbacks (to update time etc) is proving more difficult.

waveform.js provides a method which returns an object containing callbacks for soundmanager2's whileplaying and whileloading objects. I can merge this in, but this obviously removes my own callbacks.

I have tried to call the waveform.js callback functions directly,

```
whileplaying: function(){
    waveformObj.optionsForSyncedStream().whileplaying;
    updateTime();
}
```

but this gives errors along the lines of

> canvas: an attempt to set strokeStyle or fillStyle to a value that is neither a string, a CanvasGradient, or a CanvasPattern was ignored.
>   this.context.fillStyle = this.innerColor;

generated within a method of waveform.js.

I'm guessing this is something to do with resolution of *this* so I have tried using .apply but to no avail.

Any advice on getting this going is appreciated.

**Update**

When the soundmanager object is created, it takes a number of options, some of which are callbacks options look like this.

```
var opts = {
            id: _this.o.latestTrackId,
            url: _this.o.latestStream,
            autoLoad: true,
            autoPlay: autoPlay,
            multiShot: false,
            onplay: function(){
                _this.playing = true;
                _this.o.playButton.addClass('playing');
                _this.o.playButton.removeClass('paused');
                },
            onpause: function(){
                _this.playing = false;
                _this.o.playButton.removeClass('playing');
                _this.o.playButton.addClass('paused');
                },
            onresume: function(){
                _this.playing = true;
                _this.o.playButton.addClass('playing');
                _this.o.playButton.removeClass('paused');
                },
            onfinish: function(){
                },
            onstop: function(){
                },
            onload: function(){
                },
            whileloading: function(){
                _this.updateLoading();
                },
            whileplaying: function(){
                _this.setElapsed();
                _this.updatePlayhead();
                },
            stream: true,
            volume: 90
        };
```

I want to include functions from waveform.js to update the waveform, a method is provided which returns

```
whileplaying: function(),
whileloading: function()
```

I would like to include these second whileplaying / whileloading in addition to my own setElapsed(), etc but calling them directly results in the warning above.

Comment: Need more context, can we see your code? I'm not sure what `merging callbacks` means...

Comment: I've updated my question to try and give more context, hope that explains things, thanks for your help.